# How to set rails devise sign_in path as a root url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

```
devise_for :admins, path: 'admins'
```

```
devise_scope :admin do
  root to: "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

I want to redirect admins/sign_in path when I just enter above url, login     page is opening sometimes but after click on login button every time I get this error and not sign in. How to solve this problem?

*error:*

Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or 
  redirected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

look like you're trying to log in the same user again without a sign out

```
devise_for :admins, path: 'admins' 

devise_scope :admin do
  authenticated :admin do
    root 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same with this

routes.rb

```rb
root "home#index"
devise_for :admins, path: 'admins'
```

home_controller.rb

```rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
def index
   if not admin_signed_in?
     redirect_to admin_session_path
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A logged user can't sign in again...

You can try this, in your **session_controller.rb** add

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
end
```